# Is wp_read_audio_metadata() function deprecated?

Tags: uploads, media, audio

I am trying to use the function [wp_read_audio_metadata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_audio_metadata) to read the metadata for an mp3 file uploaded to a post using [acf's file field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/).

Below is my code:

```
<?php 
$audio_file = get_field('archive_audio_file'); 
$audio_file_id = $audio_file['id'];
$audio_file_path = get_attached_file( $audio_file_id);
var_dump(wp_read_audio_metadata($audio_file_path));
?>
```

When using that code I receive this error on the front end:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_read_audio_metadata()

Am I using the code incorrectly? or this **function** is **deprecated**? because I couldn't find it in `wp-includes/media.php`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`wp_read_audio_metadata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_audio_metadata) is not deprecated. It's located in `/wp-admin/includes/media.php`, which is not loaded on the front end, hence the error your're getting.

You are using the function correctly. You can make `wp_read_audio_metadata()` available by including `wp-admin/includes/media.php` before calling the function, e.g.:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$audio_file_path = get_attached_file( 1821 ); // example attachment ID
var_dump( wp_read_audio_metadata( $audio_file_path ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize the function was only accessible in wp-admin.